# How does the buffer know how many characters to transfer from the external file during a flush operation?

Tags: c++, file, buffer, streambuf, filebuf

Say I have an input operation:

```
file >> x;
```

If the internal buffer of `file` is empty `underflow()` will be called to import characters from the external device to the internal buffer of `file`. It is implementation-defined if the buffer will be partially or completely filled after this flush operation. Taking that into account, is it possible that if `x` is a string and I am expecting an input value of a certain length, that the buffer is in its right to transfer fewer characters than that? Can this happen?

Comment: I don't understand Master Bruce :D

Comment: I've never studied how streambuf works, and I never plan to.  But if no delimiter character is found before the buffer is exhausted, won't `underflow` simply be called again to retrieve more characters?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's what I figured after I wrote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real constraint on how many characters `underflow()` makes available. The only real constraint is that a stream which hasn't reached EOF needs to make, at least, one character available. With respect specifically `std::filebuf` (or `std::basic_filebuf<...>`) the stream may be unbuffered (if `setbuf(0, 0)` was called) in which case it would, indeed, make individual characters available. Otherwise, the stream will try to fill its internal buffer and rely on the operating system to have a the underlying operation return a suitable amount of bytes if there are few available, yet.

I'm not sure I quite understand your question: the operation `file >> x` will return once `x` is completely read which can happen if the stream indicated by `file` has reached its end or when a whitespace character is found (and if with "string" you mean `char*`, a non-zero value stored in `file.width()` is also taken into account). With respect to the underlying stream buffer, clearly `x` may require multiple reads to the underlying representation, i.e., it is unpredictable how many calls to `underflow()` are made. Given that the file's internal buffer is probably matching the disc's block size, I would expect that at most one call to `underflow()` is made for "normal" strings. However, if the file read is a huge and doesn't contain any spaces many calls to `underflow()` may be made. Given that the stream needs to find whitespaces it has no way to predict how many characters are needed in the first place.